# Calculate sum of digits in a mixed string

Tags: string

How can I get sum of digits in below string

```
1..4..2..6..2.212.4.11|1..4..2..6..2.|.212.4.111..2.3.444
```

I have tried this

```
String plrinfo[]=sLine.split("\\|");


            for (String plrinfo1:plrinfo) {

                System.out.println(plrinfo1);

            String[] numbers=plrinfo1.split("\\.");
            int sum=0;
                for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
                    System.out.println(numbers[i]);


            sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
            return sum
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: You should take the work of tagging the language, and formatting the example,

Comment: What are the results of your code? Can you debug your code line by line to see which line exactly cause problems?

Comment: error is-Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at playerinfo.BatsmanMain.main(BatsmanMain.java:42)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    String ip = s.nextLine();
    //replace . with space
    String ip1 = ip.replace(".", " ");
    //replace | by space
    String ip2 = ip1.replace("|", " ");
    //split string by spaces
    String[] fin = ip2.split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < fin.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(fin[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an regex(regular expression) as a string separator. This separator contains one or more "." or "|".

UPDATE: Add function **sumIndividualDigits(String str)** to get the summary of each digit of a number.

Example code:

```
public class CalculateNumber {

private static final String TEXT = "1..4..2..6..2.212.4.11|1..4..2..6..2.|.212.4.111..2.3.444";

private static final String REGEX = "(\\.|\\|)+";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] numbers = TEXT.split(REGEX);
    int sum = 0;
    for(String e : numbers) {
//            sum += Integer.valueOf(e);
//            System.out.print(e + ",");    
        int part = sumIndividualDigits(e);
        System.out.print(part + ",");
        sum += part;

    }
    System.out.println("\nSum: " + sum);
}

public static int sumIndividualDigits(String str) {

    char[] digits = str.toCharArray();
    int sum = 0;

    for(char c : digits) {
        int digit = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(c));
        sum += digit;
    }
    return sum;
}

}
```

Output is:

```
1,4,2,6,2,5,4,2,1,4,2,6,2,5,4,3,2,3,12,
Sum: 70
```

Comment: but i want 1+4+2+6+2+2+1+2+4+1+1+1..means add all individual digits.